# Executing the content of string variable as line of code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have something like

> "**_onmouseover**" : "this.className=this.className.replace(' hover',
>   '')";

I'm trying to execute it like

> buttonObject.onmouseover = function( ) {
>                 window [ this.someObject._**_onmouseover ] ()** ;      };

And I don't know how it is possible.

Let me tell you guys my scenario. I am creating this plugin to generate four types of dialogue messages in a jquery dialogue box. Those being 'Warning', 'Error', 'Note' and 'Confirm'. So lets say there are 4 spans in dom which should trigger these four.

```
<span id='DialogueWarning'> Warning </span> 
<span id='DialogueError'> Error </span> 
<span id='DialogueNote'> Note </span> 
<span id='DialogueConfirm'> Confirm </span>
```

Now lets hadle the click to show the dialogue

```
jQuery('#DialogueWarning').click(function(){

        var dialogue = new Dialogue({
            "type":"Warning",
            "message":"Are you sure you want to close this window without saving your changes?",
            "buttons":
            [
                {   
                    "text":"Close without saving", 
                    "_onmouseover": "this.className+=' hover'",
                    "_onmouseout":"this.className=this.className.replace(' hover', '')",
                    "bClass":"e_customButton"
                },

                {   
                    "text":"Don't Close",
                    "_onmouseover": "this.className+=' hover'",
                    "_onmouseout":"this.className=this.className.replace(' hover', '')",
                    "bClass":"e_customButton"
                }
            ],
            "closeOnBackgroundClick" : true
        });
    });
```

See the "_onmouseover" and _onmouseout thingy, I need those. Is there any way I can pass those in another way

Comment: Can you show handling of buttons in Dialogue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need an `eval`, I bet you have some problems in your application's design.
E.g. you can **avoid such things:**

```
// ...
var eventHandlers = {
    "_onmouseover" : "this.className=this.className.replace(' hover', '')"
};

// ...

eval(eventHandlers._onmouseover);
```

and just do it like

```
var eventHandlers = {
    _onmouseover: function(e) {
        this.className=this.className.replace(' hover', '');
    }
};

buttonObject.onmouseover = eventHandlers._onmouseover;
```

Some articles to read:

[# 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21)
[# 2](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/#eval)
[# 3](http://javascript.about.com/library/bleval.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Function` . [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CqCYp/2/)

```
buttonObject.onmouseover = Function(window [ this.someObject.__onmouseover ] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be a string in the first place?

If you had something like:

```
var someObject = {
   _onmouseover: function() {
      this.className = this.className.replace(' hover', '');
   }
}
```

You could execute it like:

```
buttonObject.onmouseover = someObject.__onmouseover;
```

If you need `this` to be the button object, you might do something like this:

```
buttonObject.onmouseover = function() {
   someObject.__onmouseover.call( buttonObject );
};
```

Comment: I think the `onclick` string is coming from a JSON-encoded reply or somesuch.

Comment: @Abody97 what leads you to believe that?

Comment: `"_onmouseover" : "this.className=this.className.replace(' hover', '')";` looks JSON-ish.

Comment: Even if it's not JSON, it's coming from an object as a string.

Comment: @Abody97 haha every object literal in javascript looks "JSONish".

Comment: @Abody97 Yes, but perhaps only because he/she doesn't know about assigning anonymous functions to properties. Hence my suggestion.

Comment: tell me more about this assigning anonymous functions to properties thing.

Comment: @srijan In the above code I have assigned an anonymous function to the _onmouseover property of the someObject object. You can pass this function around like any other variable. You can also run the function any time by adding `()` to the end of the variable. `var foo = function() { alert( 'foo' ); }; /* to run the anonymouse function... */ foo();`